# How do I install Wine on a seperate drive?

Tags: linux, symbolic-link, wine, kubuntu, ln

I have very limited space on my laptop, and Wine once fully installed, is almost 1GB in size, and I simply don't have space, and cant free up space.

Is there anyway that I could make use of symbolic linking, so I can link it to my external drive?
I try to make use of symblinking whereever possible to save space (mostly everything in my /home/ directory), and its worked great for me.

Comment: Create mount point of `/usr` into separate partition by booting into a Live USB, Copying `/usr` to that partition and editing `/etc/fstab` file. Linux software installation is not as flexible as windows, there you could choose installation directory.

Comment: What's the problem in copying the 1GB folder to the external disk with `cp -a`, then deleting and replacing it by a symbolic link?

Comment: @harrymc Well, when you install wine, there are tons of other librarys and packages it needs to get, and I cant just copy all of it over to an external drive, because it would take hours to link every single one.

Comment: But I will try @Wasif_Hasan's idea. Lets just hope I don't royally screw up my install.

Comment: You might also try a chroot jail.